# Textbox Text Disappear on Text Entry

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have a Userform that I have created, and I was wondering if it was possible to add Grey text that is there when the Userform loads but that disappears as soon as the user start to input text into the TextBox:

[image expired]

Once the user starts typing in the font color should change to black.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something Like this?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.ForeColor = &HC0C0C0 '<~~ Grey Color
    TextBox1.Text = "Please Enter Name Here"
    CommandButton1.SetFocus '<~~ This is required so that the focus moves from TB
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    With TextBox1
        If .Text = "Please Enter Name Here" Then
            .ForeColor = &H80000008 '<~~ Black Color
            .Text = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    With TextBox1
        If .Text = "" Then
            .ForeColor = &HC0C0C0
            .Text = "Please Enter Name Here"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot (In action)**

[image]

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: damn you.. beat me to it. I had almost exactly the same. XD

Comment: @user1759942: oops... Sincere apologies :)

Comment: Works very well, as long as you have the tab order set to not start on the textbox!