# Textbox Text Disappear on Text Entry Excel VBA - Part 2

Tags: excel, textbox, vba

I have a textbox1 that searches in a defined range for a matching value and goes to that cell when Enter or Command Button4 is pressed.  What I'm trying to do is have Textbox1 display "Please Enter Search Criteria" by default, which clears when a user types a value and returns when the action is completed.  The link below has everything I am looking for with the exception that I'm not using a Userform.  My textbox1 and Button4 are controls right on sheet1.  I've tried a number of ideas for a few hours and can't seem to make it work.

[Textbox Text Disappear on Text Entry Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536192/textbox-text-disappear-on-text-entry-excel-vba)

Any guidance is always appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the worksheet's activate event instead of the user form event. Pull the left drop down to select worksheet object, then pull the right drop down for the event. For this to work, you need to have dbl-clicked the worksheet in the project explorer.

Comment: I continue to get a Object doesn't support this property or method at Activesheet.button4.setfocus.

Comment: Instead of SetFocus, use Activate. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton1.Activate`